# Can SQLite sort naturally?

Tags: sqlite, sorting

Can SQLite sort naturally? For example,

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES ('Monkey');
INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES ('manatee');

SELECT name FROM animals ORDER BY name;

name      
----------
Monkey    
manatee
```

I would prefer the results to be sorted naturally (i.e., manatee, Monkey). Does SQLite not have an option to sort like this? I sort a lot of data, and if SQLite cannot sort naturally, I suppose the solution is to head back to PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ORDER BY UPPER(name)` will accomplish what you're looking for.

Additionally, you're using the [SQLite default collation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation), which means that comparisons are done using C's `memcmp` function, which compares bytes. In this case, M and m are very different. You can alter the column to have a `NOCASE` collation. Though, looking over the docs, it appears that you'll have to create a new table, copy your data into it, drop the old table and rename the new one, since the `ALTER TABLE` command only renames the table or adds a column.

Comment: Not exactly natural (it still sorts 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, etc.), but that works for the table I'm working with. Thanks!

Comment: I wish SQLite would fully support ALTER syntax, it's very annoying

Comment: @Mark: Some people do consider that natural ordering (e.g.-movie titles). If you'd like to get ideas on how to sort numerically in SQLite, please post a different question, since the parameters around it are a bit different, and it would attract those who are more familiar with SQLite than I.

Comment: No ALTER needed, you can specify collation directly in a select statement. See my answer below.

Comment: @laalto: Yes, but it still only works on a per query basis, not at the table level.

Comment: For people using SQLite in Android, I'd like to mention that Android adds `COLLATE UNICODE`, which also sorts umlauts like "ä" correctly while both `UPPER()` and `COLLATE NOCASE` operate only on ASCII characters.

Answer (score 13):

You don't have to `alter` the table to change collation:

```
SELECT name FROM animals ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE;
```

If you need more specialized sorting, you can register your own collation functions with the `sqlite3_create_collation*` family of functions and then use `COLLATE myCollationFunctionName`.